# Is there a way to expand bootstrap card dynamically?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have table inside bootstrap card:

```
<div class="card col-5">
  <div class="card-body">

    <div class="table-view">
      <div class="box table fixed-table-body">

      <table id="request_data"
      class="dataTable no-footer table  table-hover table-border" role="grid" style="overflow: visible;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
   
      </table>
      </div>
      </div>
```

The table fits into the card but when the screen is resized the table should fit into the card but it expands out, I tried writing `@media` QUERIES but nothing is working, if someone could please help out.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `table-responsive` class available in Bootstrap that you can use on a wrapping element around the table.

You could try something like this in your code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="request_data"
    class="dataTable no-footer table  table-hover table-border" role="grid" style="overflow: visible;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's some more information about it:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make the tables responsive via viewports, I have added css for your reference. However, the **codepen links** below have the working code:

```
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: .35em;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: .625em;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }

  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: .625em;
  }
  
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  table td::before {
    /*
    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
    content: attr(aria-label);
    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Some useful resources are as follows:

https://codepen.io/AllThingsSmitty/pen/MyqmdM

https://codepen.io/ismailbaskin/pen/KgAGRr

https://codepen.io/MartijnCuppens/pen/JMyOgv

Ps. Please note that these are for references only and is not my piece of work.